# How to give access to third-party Apps for Google Docs Extensions?

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

On Google Docs, extensions work perfectly with no issues. But once I use third party apps (like Typed.do) which rely completely on Google Docs (I must sign in with my Google account there actually to use the app), extensions don't work. When I try to run any extension there, it tells me "Access denied by docs.google.com". Typed.do team told me (not sure) it was a decision made by google to deny access of extensions to third-party apps by default. One member of Google Workspace community told me access can be given by the developer of the extension, so I contacted him and he (honestly) said he doesn't know how to do so (he couldn't find any resources on the web).

So is there a method that I can send to the developer which solves the problem and allows him to give access of his extension to Typed.do?

Thank you!

I searched on google and didn't find any answer.